# External source editor not working

Tags: firefox

After a fresh installation of Ubuntu 22.04 with Firefox 100.0.1 cannot see the external source editor.

Previously on Ubuntu 16.04 it worked fine with Notepad++ (Wine).
I also tried with gedit and scite with the same result.

This is the error message:

```
[Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80520006 (NS_ERROR_FILE_TARGET_DOES_NOT_EXIST) [nsIProcess.init]"  nsresult: "0x80520006 (NS_ERROR_FILE_TARGET_DOES_NOT_EXIST)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://global/content/viewSourceUtils.js :: getExternalViewSourceEditor :: line 321"  data: no].
```

Target files obviously exist

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Firefox in Ubuntu 22.04 is installed as a snap package which cannot start an external editor due to some restrictions.

It seems that the only solution to the problem is uninstalling Firefox snap and installing Firefox deb package for Ubuntu 22.04.

One way to do it is described at https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04

If you want to keep the settings from Firefox snap, move **~/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla/firefox** to **~/.mozilla/firefox** before removing the snap.